# What's the proper y-axis label for an empirical cumulative distribution plot in a publication?

Tags: data-visualization, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Examples online typically write "F(x)", but that seems confusing to readers.

Comment: I'd usually just use F(x) or occasionally $F_n(x)$ or more rarely $F^*(x)$ if I wasn't confident that it was clear we were discussing an ECDF. Sometimes I have used ECDF(x). Sometimes perhaps something else, depending on context. An ECDF *is* a cdf, so I don't think it's a big problem, but where needed, the $n$ subscript usually suffices to clearly indicate a sample quantity.

Comment: Readers in which field? What can we assume about that field and its readers? The answer depends on the precise question.

Answer (score 10):

For the y axis of an ecdf plot, you can use "Fraction of Data"  which is easier to interpret than F(x)

Comment: I think this is a reasonable answer. Others might be "Cumulative probability" and so forth. What's unclear about the question is that "publication" could mean anything from a mainstream statistics publication for which readers might be expected to recognise $F$ as an old friend to a publication in an applied field where these plots are not standard at all. (A horror example of what may need to be explained is that in fields like data journalism and business presentation a scatter plot is widely discussed as a plot that many people will find unfamiliar and difficult to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is called (empirical) *cumulative distribution* function, I tend to label the y axis

**Cumulative distribution of `x`**

This makes it very explicit and even if you would have never heard of (E)CDF, you know that the y axis shows.

For example, if we have an (E)CDF of human heights, I would label the y axis "Cumulative distribution of human heights"

Comment: A more common convention in my experience is that the axis text describes what is shown by a typical coordinate rather than by the set of coordinates. The most vivid example I can think of is that a time axis often says Time or Date and I don't think I've ever seen Times or Dates. (Such text being fairly pointless if numbers like 2000 2010 2020 are visible is a different matter.) This is just a convention and I can't think of a strong objection to "Cumulative distribution". I would just tend to use something more like "Cumulative probability".

Comment: Thanks for the comment: I should point out that I mean by x whatever is on the x axis, not the x axis itself. :) For example, if we have a ECDF of a human heights, I would label the y axis "Cumulative distribution of humans heights". But probability is, of course, also great.

Comment: Fine. I did understand the x part.